# Gunicorn graceful stopping with docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

I find that when I use docker-compose to shut down my [gunicorn](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/) (19.7.1) python application, it always takes 10s to shut down. This is the default maximum time docker-compose waits before forcefully killing the process (adjusted with the `-t / --timeout` parameter). I assume this means that gunicorn isn't being gracefully shut down. I can reproduce this with:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python

RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY test.py .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD gunicorn -b :8000 test:app
```

test.py

```
def app(_, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    data = b'Hello, World!\n'
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return iter([data])
```

Then running the app with:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and gracefully stopping it with:

```
docker-compose stop
```

version:

```
docker-compose version 1.12.0, build b31ff33
```

I would prefer to allow gunicorn to stop gracefully. I think it should be able to based on the signal handlers in [base.py](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/bc20bea7d9a86ebf2bd1cf62766ecc299b940d77/gunicorn/workers/base.py#L156).

All of the above is also true for updating images using `docker-compose up -d` twice, the second time with a new image to replace the old one.

Am I misunderstanding / misusing something? What signal does docker-compose send to stop processes? Shouldn't gunicorn be using it? Should I be able to restart my application faster than 10s?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### TL;DR

Add `exec` after CMD in your dockerfile: `CMD exec gunicorn -b :8000 test:app`.

#### Details

I had the same issue, when I ran `docker exec my_running_gunicorn ps aux`, I saw something like:

```
gunicorn     1  0.0  0.0   4336   732 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 /bin/sh -c gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py vision:app
gunicorn     5  0.1  1.1  91600 22636 ?        S    10:38   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py vision:app
gunicorn     8  0.2  2.5 186328 52540 ?        S    10:38   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py vision:app
```

The 1 PID is not the gunicorn master, hence it didn't receive the sigterm signal.

With the `exec` in the Dockerfile, I now have

```
gunicorn     1 32.0  1.1  91472 22624 ?        Ss   10:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py vision:app
gunicorn     7 45.0  1.9 131664 39116 ?        R    10:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py vision:app
```

and it works.

Comment: It works! But why does gunicorn need exec where other commands just run fine?

Comment: This is only explained under the ENTRYPOINT docs, not the CMD docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint However, I assume CMD works the same. In short, the *shell* form `CMD command param1` means the command doesn't receive signals from Docker. As documented, it runs the command with `/bin/sh -c`, like you see in the sample output in the answer. On the other hand, the *exec* form `CMD ["command", "param1"]` does receive signals from Docker. Using `CMD exec` like in this answer achieves the same thing.

Comment: I believe using the "exec form" of specifying the CMD (ex: `["gunicorn", "-c", "gunicorn.conf.py", "vision:app"]`) instead of the "shell form" would also achieve the same goal.