# GAE ERROR :- /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found

Tags: python, git, api, google-app-engine, flask

I trying to deploy my app on GAE using their trial version. I was so far successful in creating an app.yaml with a custom settings for flexible environment with python 3.6.

However, while deploying the app, the app builds successfully, however, I keep getting the following error

> Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
>   Application startup error:
>   /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found

Following is the folder hierarchy of files in my project:

[image]

Following the code for app.yaml

```
env: flex
runtime: custom
api_version: 1
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3.6

#handlers:
#- url: /SmsResponse
#  script: Twilio_Routing.RecivedSms
#
#- url: /CallResponse
#  script: Twilio_Routing.ReceivedCall
```

I am surely missing out on something and I would really appreciate some help here. 
[Link to git repo](https://github.com/afsangujarati93/TranslinkApiIntegration)

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
twilio==6.8.4
```

DockerFile

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
LABEL python_version=python3.6
RUN virtualenv --no-download /env -p python3.6

# Set virtualenv environment variables. This is equivalent to running
# source /env/bin/activate
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app/

#CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "Twilio_Routing.py" ]
```

P.S. After the changes for the requirements.txt, I am getting error 502 Bad Gateway.

Logs showing that the service was executed successfully.

```
017-12-25 01:29:03 default[20171224t212610]   * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2017-12-25 01:29:03 default[20171224t212610]   * Restarting with stat
2017-12-25 01:29:03 default[20171224t212610]   * Debugger is active!
2017-12-25 01:29:03 default[20171224t212610]   * Debugger PIN: 134-103-452
2017-12-25 01:29:17 default[20171224t212610]   * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2017-12-25 01:29:17 default[20171224t212610]   * Restarting with stat
2017-12-25 01:29:17 default[20171224t212610]   * Debugger is active!
2017-12-25 01:29:17 default[20171224t212610]   * Debugger PIN: 134-103-452
```

Can someone look at my code in git and tell me what is it that I am missing here?

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` and your `requirements.txt` please!

Comment: [**Requirements.txt**](https://github.com/afsangujarati93/TranslinkApiIntegration/blob/master/requirements.txt) and

[**Dockerfile**](https://github.com/afsangujarati93/TranslinkApiIntegration/blob/master/Transit%20Api%20Integration/Dockerfile)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the file content as (code-formatted) text.

Comment: Changes made as suggested and I believe I am missing out on adding requirements.txt file in dockerfile, but I am trying to figure out where should I place it.

Comment: My problem with this was that I misspelled requirements.txt file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few changes and I was able to run your app in docker.

1. In `Twilio_Routing.py` , change `host` to listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`.This is needed to to have the server available externally as well.
2. Since your `app.yaml` is  already configured, you don't need to customize your `Dockerfile` as  `Google App Engine` requires. Keep it as your own custom one.Here's what I used:

   ```
   #Python's Alpine Base Image
   FROM python:3.6-alpine3.6

   #Installing all python modules specified
   ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
   RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

   #Copy App Contents
   ADD . /app
   WORKDIR /app

   #Start Flask Server
   CMD [ "python","Twilio_Routing.py"]
   #Expose server port
   EXPOSE 8080
   ```

Comment: Let me give a try. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

for me the error was as simple as making sure gunicorn was in `requirements.txt`

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
```

**Note:**

I see the OP had added this flag; this is to help others that may be running into `exec: gunicorn: not found`

Answer (score 1):

Considering the example shown in the [`GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime) page, consider changing your CMD line from:

```
CMD exec gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

To:

```
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

I see [`exec` used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46237832/6309) only when the base image is the `python` one, not `gcr.io/google-appengine/python`.

Comment: I realized through your answer that I was missing to add requirements.txt in my dockerfile, which I did eventually. Later, it was giving me an error about **no module name: main**, so I replaced the CMD command with ENTRYPOINT command and it was deployed successfully. However, when I tried to access [my page](http://twilio-translink-api.appspot.com), it gave me error 502 Bad Gateway. I am kinda stuck again. What am I missing here. I have updated the dockerfile in the question as per my latest changes.

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati did you check the logs within the containers (not just docker logs)?

Comment: What if you put it app.py your app and not in main?

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this error recently when I tried to run my docker image.
/bin/sh: 1: gunicorn: not found

Simple trick that worked for me

1. delete the container and the image
2. restart the docker engine.
3. and try to create the image again using the below commands
   docker build -t <image_name>:<tag_name> .

and try to run using this command.
docker run -p 5000:5000 -e PORT =5000 image id

it worked for me! hope it helps.