# flask docker compose service takes 10s to stop

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

Simplest flask app docker image when run with `docker compose up -d` takes maximum allowed (10s) to stop when `docker compose down` is issued. I could of course set `stop_grace_period` to 1s, or set  `stop_signal: SIGKILL` in compose service, but I would like to know, is if this is an issue of how I construct an image, problem with docker, flask or base image?

app.py (same with `debug=True` as well):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_geek():
    return '<h1>Hello from Flask & Docker</h2>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

requirements.txt:
`flask`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /python-docker
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=4000"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  test_app:
    container_name: test_app
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
```

shell logs (see time on `docker compose down for test_app`):

```
myuser:/tmp/test$ docker compose up -d --build
[+] Building 1.3s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                     docker:default
 => [test_app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 252B                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [test_app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [test_app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim-buster                                                               1.2s
 => [test_app auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                           0.0s
 => [test_app 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim-buster@sha256:8799b0564103a9f36cfb8a8e1c562e11a9a6f2e3bb214e2adc23982b36a04511         0.0s
 => [test_app internal] load build context                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 131B                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [test_app 2/5] WORKDIR /python-docker                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [test_app 3/5] COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [test_app 4/5] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [test_app 5/5] COPY . .                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [test_app] exporting to image                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:535686ae7e2931c3eaea9708265c40ab0e5c44dc0c6abfebe5b2955ce938dee5                                                     0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test-test_app                                                                                                 0.0s
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network test_default  Created                                                                                                                 0.1s 
 ✔ Container test_app    Started                                                                                                                 0.1s 
myuser:/tmp/test$ docker compose down
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container test_app    Removed                                                                                                                10.4s 
 ✔ Network test_default  Removed                                                                                                                 0.3s
```

following test_app container logs nothing interesting shows up:

```
myuser:/tmp/test$ docker compose logs test_app -f
test_app  |  * Debug mode: off
test_app  | WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
test_app  |  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
test_app  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:4000
test_app  |  * Running on http://172.24.0.2:4000
test_app  | Press CTRL+C to quit
test_app  | 172.24.0.1 - - [20/Dec/2023 10:12:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
test_app  | 172.24.0.1 - - [20/Dec/2023 10:12:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
test_app exited with code 0
```

I built basic flask image based on freecodecamp example (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-dockerize-a-flask-app/), however resulting container does not stop immediately. I ran multi-stage built flask container before, running within virtual env inside Docker and containers would stop immediately.

Found this related (?) [issue: Gunicorn graceful stopping with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584760/gunicorn-graceful-stopping-with-docker-compose) but either way I tried it fails to launch flask or build.